# Special character causing issues with JS replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
var fileData = '<div name="test1"><h1>Test Div 1</h1></div><!-- Start: FindMe --><div name="findme"></div><!-- End: FindMe -->';
var findInDom = "<!-- Start: FindMe -->.*?<!-- End: FindMe -->";
var result = fileData.replace(findInDom, "");
console.log(result);
```

I'm trying to find everything from and including:

```
<!-- Start: FindMe -->
```

and

```
<!-- End: FindMe -->
```

But this code below is not replacing eveything from `<!-- Start: FindMe -->` to `<!-- End: FindMe -->` so I'm guessing it's a special character issue with `-->` causing issues maybe?

My HTML:

```
<div name="test1"><h1>Test Div 1</h1></div><!-- Start: FindMe --><div name="findme"></div><!-- End: FindMe -->
```

My Regex/replace:

```
var findInDom = "<!-- Start: FindMe -->.*?<!-- End: FindMe -->";
```

My Regex with variable:

```
var findInDom = /<!-- Start: " + name + " -->.*?<!-- End: " + name + " -->/;
```

--- name being a variable.

Any ideas why this is not replacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findInDom` is a string, but you're treating it like a regular expression.

Instead, you want to use a regular expression like so:

```
var findInDom = /<!-- Start: FindMe -->.*?<!-- End: FindMe -->/;
```

If you want to insert the values of variables into your regex, use the regex constructor instead:

```
var name = "FindMe";
var findInDom = "<!-- Start: " + name + " -->.*?<!-- End: " + name + " -->";
var regex = new RegExp(findInDom);
var result = fileData.replace(regex);
```

Comment: Oops...my bad. What happens if I want to pass in a variable though, that's why I was using it as a string?

Comment: You should use this too then, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/772035, and use `Regex.escape( name )` instead of just `name` directly, in case `name` contains characters that get interpreted with special meaning in regex, such as if name contains a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using String to replace. Try `fileData.replace(new RegExp(findInDom, 'g'),"")`